# Grep match a certain key/value set json

Tags: regex, json, bash, grep

IF THIS IS THE FIRST TIME YOU"RE READING THIS QUESTION, SKIP RIGHT TO THE EDIT

So what I'm trying to do is match everything until a certain word
What I'm working with is similar to this:

```
{"selling":"0"morestuffhere"notes":"otherthingshere"}unwantedthingshere
```

The regex I got so far is:

```
grep -o "\{\"selling\":\"0\""
```

which will match up to `{"selling":"0"`.

I want it to match `{"selling":"0"morestuffhere"notes":"otherthingshere"}` but NOT `unwantedstuffhere`.

I don't know beforehand what "morestuffhere", "otherthingshere" and "unwantedstuffhere" are gonna be. So what I want to do is match everything from what I already have until `"notes":"otherthingshere"}`.

How do I do this?

EDIT: forgot to mention some key points. Sorry, had to hurry because dinner was ready.

My input consists of a series of key:value sets, as such:

```
{"key":"value", "otherkey":"othervalue","morekeys":"morevalues"},{"othersetkey":"othersetvalue","otherothersetkey":"otherothersetvalue","othersetmorekeys":"othersetmorevalues"}
```

and so on.

The first key/value set is different from the rest of them, and I don't want to match that set.

The first key of all sets other than the first is `"selling"`, and I want to match all sets that have a "selling" value of 1. The last key of the set is `"notes"`.

The input is JSON, so I added that to the tags.

Comment: Would it be appropriated to say you want to match everything until the `}` character?

Comment: What is the "certain word" that you want to match up to?

Comment: What format would you like the output displayed in?

Comment: You can't rely on the ordering of key:value pairs inside a hash so there's really no "first key/value set".

Answer (score 2):

Through sed,

```
sed -r 's/^[^{]*([^}]*).*$/\1}/g' file
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'dSDGAadb{"selling":"0"morestuffhere"notes":"otherthingshere"}unwantedthingshere' | sed -r 's/^[^{]*([^}]*).*$/\1}/g'
{"selling":"0"morestuffhere"notes":"otherthingshere"}
```

I think you want something like this,

```
$ cat aa
dSDGAadb{"selling":"0"morestuffhere"notes":"otherthingshere"}{"selling":"1"morestuffhere"notes":"otherthingshere"}bgj
$ sed -r 's/.*(\{"selling":"1"[^}]*)}.*/\1}/g' aa
{"selling":"1"morestuffhere"notes":"otherthingshere"}
```

OR

something like this,

```
$ cat aa
dSDGAadb{"selling":"0"morestuffhere"notes":"otherthingshere"}{"selling":"1"morestuffhere"notes":"otherthingshere"}bgj{"selling":"1"morestuffhere"notes":"otherthingshere"}

$ grep -oP '{\"selling\":\"1\"[^}]*}' aa
{"selling":"1"morestuffhere"notes":"otherthingshere"}
{"selling":"1"morestuffhere"notes":"otherthingshere"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with `grep`:

```
grep -o '{[^}]*}' file
```

This matches an opening curly brace, followed by anything that isn't a closing curly brace, followed by a closing curly brace.

Testing it out on your input:

```
$ grep -o '{[^}]*}' <<<'{"selling":"0"morestuffhere"notes":"otherthingshere"}unwantedthingshere'
{"selling":"0"morestuffhere"notes":"otherthingshere"}
```

Comment: @user3688448 your edit changes things quite considerably! If you show some sample input and output in your question, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with

```
>> grep -o ".*}" file.txt
{"selling":"0"morestuffhere"notes":"otherthingshere"}
```

where `file.txt` contains your example string?

Answer (score 0):

I've never found a good way to do this kind of thing with json in the shell with basic unix tools like grep, sed, etc.  A quick and dirty ruby or python script is your friend,

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# h.rb

require 'json'

key=ARGV.shift
json=ARGF.read
h=JSON.parse(json)
puts h.key?(key) ? h[key] : "not found"
```

And then pipe your json into the script specifying the key as a parameter,

```
$ echo '{"key":"value", "otherkey":"othervalue","morekeys":"morevalues"}' | /tmp/h.rb otherkey
othervalue
```

or from a file,

```
$ cat /tmp/h.json | /tmp/h.rb otherkey
othervalue
```